# Unattended-upgrades: figuring out a origins pattern

Tags: unattended-upgrades

While setting up a Ubuntu server, I installed ZeroTier, and configured `unattended-upgrades` as always. ZeroTier is a problem child when it comes to unattended-upgrades, because all of the origin data is just the distro name repeated over and over, i.e.:

```
500 http://download.zerotier.com/debian/mantic mantic/main amd64 Packages
    release o=mantic mantic,a=mantic,n=mantic,l=mantic mantic,c=main,b=amd64
    origin download.zerotier.com

Origin: mantic mantic
Label: mantic mantic
Suite: mantic
Codename: mantic
Date: Mon, 30 Oct 2023 18:45:47 UTC
Architectures: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 ppc64el s390x
Components: main
Description: Generated by aptly
```

This is clearly not terribly useful. On all of my Debian machines, the following entry works fine in `50unattended-upgrades`:

`"site=download.zerotier.com,n=${distro_codename}";`

While not ideal, it works. However, in this Ubuntu server, this doesn't work, falling over with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/unattended-upgrades", line 2522, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(options))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/unattended-upgrades", line 1993, in main
    res = run(options, rootdir, mem_log, logfile_dpkg,
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/unattended-upgrades", line 2134, in run
    cache = UnattendedUpgradesCache(rootdir=rootdir)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/unattended-upgrades", line 156, in __init__
    self.allowed_origins = get_allowed_origins()
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/unattended-upgrades", line 793, in get_allowed_origins
    allowed_origins = get_allowed_origins_legacy()
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/bin/unattended-upgrades", line 772, in get_allowed_origins_legacy
    (distro_id, distro_codename) = s.split()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

This is a surprise to me, as I didn't realize that Ubuntu and Debian would be far enough apart to make unattended-upgrades fall over. Commenting out the source line makes unattended-upgrades work correctly again, so that's definitely the problem.

Any suggestions on what might be making this entry fail, given the origin information I have?

Comment: If the Origin is "mantic mantic" and the Release is "mantic/main", then the string for `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` should be `"mantic mantic:mantic/main";`

Comment: apt in both Ubuntu and Debian are not far apart. They share most of the same developers. Lot of work on apt in the past couple years, so you might see differences between older and newer versions of apt.

Comment: You don't think that `"mantic mantic:mantic/main"` will hit anything else? I sort of dismissed that internally because it seemed like it would be a wildcard, but given that it has two arguments, and so does everything else, I suppose it would be a unique identifier, wouldn't it?

Comment: Check the Origin field of all your apt sources to see if any others use "mantic mantic". Your output shows that you know how. Then you will know.

Comment: This has been a very zen discussion :) At the end, though, I feel as though this was a form of premature-optimization. Since none of the other sources match the nonsense, then...from chaos comes form. 

Also, it works fine :)